# Unable to run groovy script with jmeter

Tags: groovy, jmeter

My code to assert response :

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

sleep(5000)
def ResponseMessage = messageExchange.response.responseContent
def jsonString = new JsonSlurper().parseText(ResponseMessage)


assert !(jsonString.isEmpty())
assert jsonString.code == 200
```

Error from Jmeter :

```
> 2017/05/15 21:37:20 ERROR - jmeter.timers.JSR223Timer: Problem in
> JSR223 script JSR223 Timer javax.script.ScriptException:
> javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No
> such property: messageExchange for class: Script19    at
> org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:155)
>   at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(Unknown Source)   at
> org.apache.jmeter.util.JSR223TestElement.processFileOrScript(JSR223TestElement.java:220)
>   at org.apache.jmeter.timers.JSR223Timer.delay(JSR223Timer.java:42)
>   at
> org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.delay(JMeterThread.java:806)
>   at
> org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:458)
>   at
> org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:418)
>   at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:249)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
> javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No
> such property: messageExchange for class: Script19    at
> org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:346)
>   at
> org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:152)
>   ... 8 more Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such
> property: messageExchange for class: Script19     at
> org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:53)
>   at
> org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoGetPropertySite.getProperty(PogoGetPropertySite.java:52)
>   at
> org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGroovyObjectGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:307)
>   at Script19.run(Script19.groovy:5)  at
> org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:343)
>   ... 9 more
```

I have already imported necessay jars for groovy support but still have error regarding `messageExchange`.

Comment: Your error says you don't have property `com`, but there is no `com` in your script. Your description says it complains about `messageExchange`. Please bring your question in shape, synchroizing, source, error and description.

Comment: @Vampire - If I use same script in SOAP UI then it works fine. Problem occur with Jmter only :(

Comment: @Vampire - I have updated error.

Comment: Where do you expect `messageExchange` to come from? You are not defining it in the script, hence the error

Comment: @KirilS. - But same script working fine in SOAP UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to use Groovy in this context, the situation can be handled via [JSON Path Assertion](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathAssertion/)

So you can kill two birds with one stone by adding the JSON Path Assertion as a child of your request and configuring it as follows:

- JSON Path: `$.code`
- Check `Validate against expected value` box
- Put `200` into the "Expected Value" input field

  [image: JMeter JSON Path Assertion[2]]

You can install JSON Path Assertion using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager), look for "JSON Plugins" under the "Available Plugins" tab

[image: JMeter Plugins Manager - JSON Plugin]

---

If you still need to do this in Groovy the correct way of getting parent sampler response data would be:

1. Switch to [JSR223 Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion) instead of JSR223 Timer as timers are executed **before** samplers therefore you won't be able to access current sampler result from it
2. Use the following code to get the response data as JSON and validate `code` attribute value:

   ```
   def ResponseMessage = SampleResult.getResponseData()
   def jsonString = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(ResponseMessage)

   if (!jsonString.code.equals("200")) {
       AssertionResult.setFailure(true)
       AssertionResult.setFailureMessage("Response code was: " + jsonString.code)
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Soap UI and JMeter are not compatible in any way. Soap UI has a built-in object called `messageExchange`, JMeter does not. From [MessageExchange](http://www.soapui.org/apidocs/com/eviware/soapui/model/iface/MessageExchange.html) definition, it looks like they are talking about previous request result. So my guess is that an equivalent in JMeter is an object called `prev`.

```
def ResponseMessage = prev.getResponseDataAsString();
```

You also should be using Groovy post-processor to the object from which you want to be obtaining the result, while right now it looks like you are using the timer.

Comment: It says : **java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method getResponseDataAsString() on null object**

Comment: I am sending **API GET REQUEST** and just after that I have put **JSR223 Timer** for groovy script.

Comment: As I said, you cannot use Timer, if you want a result of previous sampler: you need to add post-processor UNDER sampler (right click on Sampler, under post-processors > choose JSR223 post-processor, copy your script into that object)

Comment: Should I store response anywhere to assert into JSR223?

Comment: As long as you use it in post-processor, you have access to it directly (via `prev` object) and don't need to store it.

Comment: Yes if I print like **log.info ResponseMessage**, It prints my whole json response. But how can I print particular parameter value from whole json response? for ex: print only **Date** from json response.

Comment: For that, you don't even need groovy post-processor. Use Json Extractor: http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor
much easier that way

Answer (score 1):

Do you maybe confuse JMeter with SOAPUI?

As you do not define `messageExchange` anywhere in your script, the one calling the script should have set it. This is not the case, hence the error message. SOAPUI as far as I remember sets a `messageExchange` property, JMeter obviously does not.

Comment: I see. Then how can I define *messageExchnage* in jmeter?

Comment: Look at the JMeter documentation? I guess there is also some variable defined in JMeter with which you can access the response, but SOAPUI and JMeter are not compatible in any way regarding this.